# Is there a way to keep searching after unique index has found a match

Tags: mysql, indexing, insert, unique

I have a table with two unique indexes, a username and email. If it finds a duplicate username I would also like to be able to keep searching to see if the email is also a duplicate. This is just so I can display the error so the user doesn't have to submit the form twice to find out both fields were wrong. If not is there another option I can use? I could use a select with a where clause, but didn't really want to go that root.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

```
  SELECT
    ( SELECT  "dup username" FROM t WHERE username = '...' ),
    ( SELECT  "dup email" FROM t WHERE email = '...' );
```

will return a row with 2 columns.  Each column will give an error message or `NULL`.

Plan B:

```
    ( SELECT  "dup username" FROM t WHERE username = '...' )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  "dup email" FROM t WHERE email = '...' );
```

will return 0, 1, or 2 rows.